# Where should font settings for cell.titleLabel go in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

Should I put set the font of a `cell.titleLabel` in the `cell == nil` portion of the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method? or after? I'm also adding some labels and a `UIImage` programmatically. The `UIImage` doesn't change but the value of the labels does.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  static NSString *identifier = @"identifier";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];

 [cell.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Asap-Bold" size: 15.0f]];
      [cell.descriptionLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Asap-Regular" size: 10.0f]];

  }

  **// or should it go here?**

  return cell;
}
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: @Vishal is this incorrect then? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9135341/388458 thanks

Comment: Does the font change depending on the content of the row? If not, resetting it every time you access a cell seems unnecessary.

Comment: @RichTolley the font always stays the same. I'm looking to speed up table performance and want to move all the static items to the appropriate place. Would that be within the if (cell == nil) { .... }  ?

Comment: you are doing it correct... it won't be called again and again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right setting font in braces because this code should be executed once. Outside braces should be the code that getting access to your data source e.g. when you doing smth like this
`cell.label.text = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:i];`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  static NSString *identifier = @"identifier";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
     //executed once per cell
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault          reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
    [cell.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Asap-Bold" size: 15.0f]];
    [cell.descriptionLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Asap-Regular" size: 10.0f]];
  }
//Executed every time
 cell.label.text = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:i];
  return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if cell font is independent of row number then it always have to go inside if(cell == nil).